# as3- passing a rectangle to sprite.graphics.drawRect( )

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, refactoring

Is there a neat minimal way of doing this? (this produces an error):

```
var freeSpace = shape.freeSpace() // returns Rectangle

var s:Sprite = new Sprite();

s.graphics.drawRect(freeSpace);
```

Just looking for a more cleaner way other than something like `.drawRect(freeSpace.x, freeSpace.y, freeSpace.w, freeSpace.h)`

I know you can do it with `bitmapData.fillRect(rectangle)`, but need sprites in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own class which extends Sprite

```
public class SpritePlus extends Sprite
```

and imlpements a method which does this:

```
public function drawRect(rect:Rectangle):void {
  this.graphics.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var freeSpace:Rectangle = shape.freeSpace();
var s:SpritePlus = new SpritePlus();
s.drawRect(freeSpace);
```

But in my opinion, it's alright to use the Sprite's native method.

```
s.graphics.drawRect(freeSpace.x, freeSpace.y, freeSpace.width, freeSpace.height);
```

Comment: nice one thanks. yeah I guess its quite pedantic, just seeing how my code could look a little clearer.